# Identify invalid field values during GSON deserialization

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization

I have an Order object in my application which takes the JSON format as follows.

```
{
    "id" : "1001",
    "amount" : 100.50
    "customer" : {
         "id" : "2001"
         "name" : "Ned Stark"
    }
}
```

This is represented as the following POJO.

```
public class Order 
{
    private long id;
    private double amount;
    private Customer customer;
}
```

I use GSON to serialize and deserialize this POJO. Everything works fine until the input values given in the JSON are valid.

But when I give an invalid data type value in JSON, GSON doesn't throw an exception specific to the error prone field but just a generic exception, which gives the app no idea which field value is invalid.

For instance, **if I give amount as "asdf" (instead of a valid number) in JSON, during deserialization Gson just throws a generic NumberFormatException, but doesn't seem to provide any information that the exception has happened actually when the field "amount" is being trying to set** with the input value.

This will be typically useful to the app when it has to communicate the apt error to the client. I assume there should be someway to achieve this in GSON.

Is there any format to find the specific field that has caused the deserialization failure?

Comment: Same kind of issue, i resolved by just adding Object mapper dependency and convert using that. You can configure multiple things in this as well.

Comment: Thanks Jango. I tried ObjectMapper. That prints the field name in the JsonMappingException's toString call, but it doesn't seem to expose the JSON field as a data in that exception - something like exception.getJSONKeyOfInvalidData() - so that I could set this as a key in response JSON for the client to process.
Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on a third party library you can write a validator before serialization.

This way you have complete control on messages to be communicated in case of errors.

Comment: I just thought of not reinventing the wheel. Serializer does the conversion for me. I don't prefer to iterate through all the JSON keys before serializing and then let the serializer do another iteration while serializing.